# Unit conversions, permissions, and other transforms in Flux & React

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux

Straight to the point: where do behaviors like unit conversions (for display & input), permissions checks, and other presentation related transforms belong in a Flux architecture?

An example of "other presentation related transforms" in our case is applying user layout settings to a view. For example, a user can define what data fields to see in a summary view, and in which order to see those.

We think we understand part of this problem solution: these transforms are application state and live in various state stores ("WeekSummaryLayoutStore", "UnitPreferencesStore"). The flow to set/get, edit, and retrieve those states is well understood.

What we would like to explore is where to APPLY those states to obtain the final presentation result and be in alignment with the Flux architecture. We have come up with a variety of options:

1) React component Mixin handles things like unit conversion in the "render" method of each leaf component. Various presentation state stores are DI'ed into the component's constructor, and the Mixin automagically wires things up (listen to various state stores, updates, etc).

2) Use an intermediary store, WeekSummaryPresentationDataStore, which listens to the WeekSummaryDataStore, WeekSummaryLayoutStore, and the UnitPreferencesStores and spits out final presentation data; the component then listens to the proper ***PresentationStore and deals with updates & renders like it would with any other store.

3) Integrate all transformations in the original data store and let the store only spit out presentation-ready data.

Arguments for/against each?

1) The final leaf component should be the only module to know about how to "present" the data. Arguably, unit conversions, applying layouts, and determining the data detail based on permissions is part of this presentation logic. Several extra layers, but nicely decoupled, original data store doesn't need to know anything about further transforms. Core business logic of each store can be reused across components, each component can then present data differently based on various presentation state stores.

2) Added complexity for what?

3) Arguably, *some* presentation logic is part of business logic and could be owned by the core data store. Significantly reduces complexity, but allows for duplication of business logic if components need same core store but different presentation state.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

If your transformations are "pure" functions, then they can live in a Utils module.  DateTimeUtils, for example.  I mean "pure" in the functional programming sense: stateless, with no need for any stateful information that is not passed in through the method's parameters.  Same inputs always result in the same output.

Utils are bags of static functions have no application-specific dependencies (though a WebAPIUtils module is a notable exception to this rule, as it needs all the data in the stores required for an API call).  These application-dependency-free Utils modules can now be required in any component or store that needs them.

You could create a mixin for the view layer instead, sure.  But I personally prefer static method Utils modules to mixins, because it makes it easier to understand where a method is defined.

As far as whether you should store the transformations, I think you probably should not, but this is probably something that needs to be decided on a case-by-case basis.  This feels like tightly coupling your view and data layers, and they should probably operate more independently.